# Where did the "Safe Removal" in the Disks (Disk Utility) application go in 12.10?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, power-management

In the Disk Utility in 12.04, there is a "Safe Removal" option for removable hard drives.

[image: A screenshot of the Disk Utility in Ubuntu 12.04 with the "Safe Removal" button highlighted]

In the equivalent Disks utility in 12.10, this option has disappeared.

[image: A screenshot of the "Disks" utility in Ubuntu 12.10]

Where did it go? How do I safely remove a drive? (The Safely Remove option powers down the device, unlike merely dismounting.)

Answer (score 0):

You can safely remove a drive from the file manager itself. There is an icon alongside the volumes that have been mounted.

[image: Nautilus Screenshot]

The icon you need to click it the one to the right on the `Data` label under the `Devices`, of course the label will be different for your volumes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, that only dismounts the device, not safely removes it. For example, I have an external USB hard drive with several partitions. If I click the icon for every mounted partition, the device still remains attached and powered on, and I can remount.

Answer (score 0):

In 14.04 (and probably 12.10 and other versions too), click the **gears** button at the top right ("More actions"), then click **Power off**.